# Will game-sharing on xbox one also share content from a deluxe digital edition?

Tags: xbox-one

I'm planning on getting black ops 3 digital deluxe edition, but I think this applies to many games with bundled content.

Will another user signed into my xbox have access to all the extra content from a digital bundle, I.e. DLC, maps, items, even if I'm not signed in? Or does their account just get access to the game, and they have to buy their own extras through their profile?

Edit: Just for the record, this is not a subversive strategy, Xbox advertises game-sharing functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Xbox One you're playing on is designated as your home console, yes. From the [About my Home Xbox Setting](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/games/my-home-xbox) on Xbox Support:

> Share games and downloadable content purchased from the digital store with anyone else who signs in on your console. You can even share games downloaded as part of a subscription.